# Limit php execution time

Tags: php

I make dig query. Sometime the reply is fast and sometimes it's more than 10 seconds. My question is I need to stop the query if it's after 5 seconds and then update the database. So that was the question how can I get `$ip` to stop after 5 sec to update my database?

```
$host = "@$ns1 $subdomain";
$ip = `/usr/bin/dig $host +short A`;

// if $ip is more than 5 sec than stop the query. How to do this?

mysql_query("UPDATE dns SET query_ns = '1' WHERE zone ='123'");
```

**Update**:
I am so sorry for any confusion. What I meant by `query` is using dig to make ns lookup. So sorry once again.

Comment: In PHP, not much - PHP will be suspended while dig is running, and time spent in external commands does not count against PHP's normal execution time limit settings.

Comment: there is a timeout option in dig, `+time=5`, you can apply the timeout and expect only GOOD result should return from the bash

Comment: Based on my experience with unreliable APIs, it can be an idea to make the requests separately with a cronjob. You cache the results, and then make your request to the cache, not to the API. The use of this depends on the project, but it can be a workaround the the problem you're describing.

Comment: @ajreal: I try `dig +time=5 @hii.com hello.lol.me +short A` or `dig @hii.com hello.lol.me +short +time=5 A`it didn't work. The query didn't stop after 5 second. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Ah yeah based on the code sample the only "query" I saw was MySQL lol but yes in the event of using dig, use the +time parameter in your command and you'll either get a result back, or get nothing back. If you get nothing, then it either timed out or returned nothing.

Comment: @sg552 if the timeout isn't working, your best bet would be what Alex posted below. That would give you the timeout in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You could use proc_open to open pipe to the dig command, stream_select it and wait for 5 seconds, read after that and close the proc.

More or less this way:

```
function getip()
{
$ip = null;

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")  // stderr
);

$process = proc_open("/usr/bin/dig $host +short A", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // 2 => readable handle


    $ip = fgetsPending($pipes[1]);

    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    proc_close($process);
}

return $ip;
}

function fgetsPending(&$in,$tv_sec=5) 
{
    if ( stream_select($read = array($in),$write=NULL,$except=NULL,$tv_sec) ) return fgets($in);
    else return FALSE;   
}

echo getip();
```

Comment: I declare global variable inside function and it still won't work. The only way I test it work is when I manually assign value to `$process = proc_open('/usr/bin/dig @ns01.000webhost.com. hello.cheapantivirus.me. +short A', $descriptorspec, $pipes);` Can you show me some example of using my outside variable with your function. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: In my code `'/usr/bin/dig $host +short A'` I use single quotes to wrap the command. PHP does not interpret variables in single quotes. Change it into `"/usr/bin/dig $host +short A"`. I've edited the answer above.

Comment: The IP is shown now when the nameserver is valid but when I test it with invalid data like `@hii.com hello.lol.me` the query still not stop after 10 seconds. However the problem has been solved. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the mysql_unbuffered_query function:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php

Something along these lines should do what you want:

```
<?php
// a db link for queries
$lh  = mysql_connect( 'server', 'uname', 'pword' );
// and a controller link
$clh = mysql_connect( 'server', 'uname', 'pword', true );

if ( mysql_select_db ( 'big_database', $lh ) )
{
  $began  =  time();
  $tout   = 60 * 5; // five minute limit
  $qry    = "SELECT * FROM my_bigass_table";
  $rh     = mysql_unbuffered_query( $qry, $lh );
  $thread = mysql_thread_id ( $lh );
  while ( $res = mysql_fetch_row( $rh ) )
  {
    /* do what you need to do
     * ...
     * ...
     */
    if ( ( time() - $began ) > $tout )
    {
      // this is taking too long
      mysql_query( "KILL $thread", $clh );
      break;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's the call to dig which is too long.

Comment: Looks like both Brian and I assumed "query" meant "MySQL query".

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but I'd try something like this:

```
$default_exe_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
try {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 5);
    $host = "@$ns1 $subdomain";
    $ip = `/usr/bin/dig $host +short A`;
    if (!mysql_query("UPDATE dns SET query_ns = '1' WHERE zone ='123'")){
        throw new Exception('');
    }
} catch Exception ($e) {
   // update db
}
ini_set('max_execution_time', $default_exe_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with mysql extension (it doesn't have such function or settings) but you can do it easy with mysqli in procedural way:

```
mysqli_options($connection, MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

or in OOP way:

```
$connection->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
```

You can read about mysqli and its functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php)

Answer (score 1):

Per the official documentation, *"PHP will attempt to execute the contents of the backticks as a shell command"*, which means you should be able to do as follows:

```
$ip = `/usr/bin/dig $host +short A   & pid=$! ; sleep 5; kill -9 $pid`
```

This trick works in the shell, so if PHP executes the backticks in a shell, you should be good.

EDIT: You might need to apply some extra polish so PHP doesn't attempt to expand `$pid`...

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to using `mysqli` and use the `mysqli_kill()` command: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.kill.php

Comment: You should switch to mysqli for many reasons, but yes it does have a function that does exactly what the code I posted above does.

Comment: Indeed - simplicity-wise I think yours is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved and thanks to ajreal for giving me his idea. I decide to limit query by dig utilities instead. Solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/360102/dig-timeout-option-dont-work

Thanks for everyone help and input.